# Liferay CMS with custom build web-site

Tags: content-management-system, liferay-6

I have built a website (using php & codeigniter) and need to build CMS for the website using Liferay. Thus the website will either pull the content from Liferay through web service or Liferay will promote xml/json to some place where website will read it.

Does anyone have any links or pointers to how this can be done.

Thank you 
-- MB

Answer (score 1):

Whole Liferay's API is accessible through SOAP / JSON web services. If you want to pull Web Content from Liferay, you could use `get-articles` method from `journalarticle` service. You can browse Liferay services using `http://yourhost/api/jsonws` URL.

This feature is well documented in the following articles from Liferay's official docs:

- https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/remotely-accessing-liferay-services-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-18--1
- https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/accessing-services-remotely-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-05-en